# Is the complex version of fourier series easier to use when we have piecewise jump discontinuous function?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series, real-numbers

Is the complex version of the fourier series allow us to represent piecewise functions more easily than real version?

Comment: What does «more easily» mean ?

Comment: They are equivalent.